# Custom UITableViewCell is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am using xib to load the cell in the `UITableViewController`. There is a button on the cell by hitting which a modal pops up and when we hit something on that modal, I want to change the image in the cell. But I am not able to get the cell even if I am passing the indexPath.
I have used following code:

```
    NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender inSection:0];
    [self.tableView2 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I have  written the code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
    if([[feedbackDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Key%li",indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",indexPath.row]])

            {
                NSLog(@"Yay! Feedback");
                cell.checkmark.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Oops! No feedback");
                cell.checkmark.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangetick"];
            }
```

I am supposing that when `reloadrows` will run,it will reload that particular cell by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But it is of no help. The image is not changing at all.

Secondly, I tried to get the cell by using following

```
    NSIndexPath *ip=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:button.tag inSection:0];
    ExpandingCell *cell=(ExpandingCell*) [_tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
     NSLog(@"No cell");
    }
```

I am getting no cell as output. Please help.

Comment: You should add some kind of animation to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` if you expect `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the cause of your problem is.  Certainly you are correct that `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` is the right way to reload a specific set of table rows.  However, I did notice that this code: `if([[feedbackDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Key%li",indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",indexPath.row]])` will never return `YES`, so you will never get a "tick" image.

Comment: @nobre Actually, `UITableView` should call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` regardless of whether you use animation.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo the above said code is returning true when I reload the cell by scrolling the tableView up and down. It is changing the image but I want to change it instantly when the button gets clicked.

Comment: @nobre Animation din't work.

Comment: @RamdeepSingh Sorry, you're right.  I didn't see the `objectForKey`.  It's a rather long line of code.

Comment: In the first case, are you sure that `sender` is the correct row?  In the second case, are you sure that `button.tag` is the correct row index?  Note that cells are reused in a `UITableView` to reduce memory consumption.  As soon as a cell scrolls off the top of the screen, it will be put in a pool and is eligible for reuse (based on its reuse identifier).  This means that the same instance may be used for multiple cells in the table.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that millions of times. sender and button.tag both are giving me correct row.

Comment: Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called? Relying on the cell object itself is not great. You should persist the data in your model, and just let the tableview reload and draw what the model tells it. Scrolling, rotating, moving out of visible rows can all make your cell get reused

Comment: After searching for so many days, I have found that  tableView is also nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and fixed it. The problem was when modal pops up,it was loosing control over the view controller and that is why tableview is null and nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0):

At first, to debug it try to call `[self.tableView2 reloadData]`. If your image is changed, it means that you were called wrong indexPath for `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method.
Also `button.tag` could return wrong tag, because cells are reusable in UITableView, and it can be cell that already used before.

Comment: I have already checked the button.tag. It is giving me correct index.

Comment: Have you tried `reloadData`? Can you provide your `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` method implementation?